# rsync does not sync uppercase/ lowercase in filenames. How can I make it sync caps?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync, web-deployment

We are using shell scripts to deploy applications through the different servers (DTAP). The only problem is that when caps are changed these are not synced.

For example:

> aboutcontroller.php > AboutController.php

We are using the following rync command.

```
rsync -avz git/folder/ public_html/folder/
```

Does anyone know how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Do you mean that file it removes capitalization, or do you mean it does not match files whose names differ only in their capitalization?

Comment: It sounds more like a filesystem problem than an rsync problem. Is the source on a Mac by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not likely `rsync` itself, but the case-insensitivity of either the source or destination filesystem (or both). When `rsync` says "give me the contents of file `foo`", and the file system responds with the contents of `FOO` instead, because it for whatever reason thinks that case insensitivity is a "good thing", there's not much that `rsync` can do to accomplish the "right thing". This will be an issue on common file systems used by Windows and Mac platforms, but not so much on Unix/Linux (except where they support Windows/Mac file systems as well).

Comment: We are developing on windows > committing to git > deploying on Centos. I would think that Linux as it is case sensitive would take this in to account.

Comment: Note to self: my USB drive partition with APFS needs to be changed to APFS case sensitive if I want to sync my photos from my ext4 server.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does take this into account. However if you feed it Foo.h today but then your case insensitive file system sends it foo.h tomorrow (with different contents you'll end up with two file (foo.h and Foo.h) on Linux and you'll confuse everybody.